# Left Join in Linq gives an error

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

```
Table : tblEmp 
EmpId  EmpName ManagerId
101    john     Null
102    jack     101
```

The foll. query gives an error that the materialized value is null. Where am i going wrong. Please note that the EmpId & ManagerId are actually GUIDs in table.

Using c#, linq to entities

```
public DataTable GetData(guid id)
{
  var qry = from e in MYDB.tblEmps.where(e=>e.EmpId==id)
            join m in MYDB.tblEmps on e.ManagerId equals m.EmpId into emp_mgr
            from m in emp_mgr.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new
            {
              name = m.empname ?? string.empty,
              id = e.managerid  //also tried e.managerid ?? guid.empty
            }
   DataTable dt = qry.ToDataTable();
   return dt;
}
```

Comment: I don't really use query syntax so I'm not positive about this but, should you be using `==` here rather than `=`? `e.ManagerId = m.EmpId into emp_mgr`

Comment: oh.Typo. It was 'equals'.updated.

Comment: ERROR - The cast to value type 'Guid' failed because the materialized value is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your should checkk m on null, in select statement. Also you have error in join syntax (should be equals):

```
var qry = from e in MYDB.tblEmps.where(e=>e.EmpId==id)
          join m in MYDB.tblEmps on e.ManagerId equals m.EmpId into emp_mgr
          from m in emp_mgr.DefaultIfEmpty()
          select new
          {
              name = m != null && m.empname != null ? m.empname : string.empty,
              id = e.managerid  //also tried e.managerid ?? guid.empty
          }
```

Comment: This seems reasonable however, this is LINQ to Entities, not LINQ to Objects. Rows are not NULL in SQL (you can have NULL as a value in a column or 0 rows but you can't have a null row). That select is going to be translated into `SELECT m.empname, e.managerid`. m and e are table aliases and can't be null, there aren't references in SQL, it just doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 0):

After a little research my suspicion is that `qry` is null when you call `ToDataTable()` on it. So I would just change the last couple lines to;

```
  if (qry == null)
     return null;
  else
     return qry.ToDataTable();
```

You can confirm if that is really the source of the problem by setting a break point on your current `qry.ToDataTable()` line and confirming whether or not `qry` is null at that point but I'm pretty confident that is the issue because null references aren't really a thing in your L-E query.